# How to display ContextMenu underlined text at execution time?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

This is my ContextMenu, as you can see I put some dashes under specific letters to acces to the menu items via Keyborad, so for example for the `Close` menu item I only need to press `C` (Not necessary `Ctrl+C`)

[image]

But I have two issues here:

1· The underlined text is not shown at execution time, I don't know if this is normal but I would like to show them.

[image]

> UPDATE

I've found a comment [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/407e4e8a-9328-4bc4-8f2a-d7424e3d7a76/context-menu-not-being-underlined-at-runtime?forum=csharpgeneral) explaining that an option on the `Easy Of Access` controlpanel need to be activated in order to display the underlined keys... but I didn't find that option (Im on Windows 8), anyways my intention is to display them without touching the SO settings.

2· Is it possibly to hack the menu item's `ShortCutKeys` property to avoid the usage of a modifier to display something like `None + C` ? because it's stupid display info of a modifier when I previously set an underlined character to avoid the modifiers usage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> at the execution time.

Comment: Thankyou so much, you know where is documented that? it works but it can be done with some kind of property? My last resource is to send a "ALT" key pulsation after loading the form but I don't think that is the right way to enable the accelerator keys

Comment: Done, here is the trick: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27367/Enabling-Hot-Keys-Short-Cut-keys-for-windows-Appli